# Device in Test Mode Admob

Tags: android, testing, admob, device

I have a doubt with the testmode in AdMob.

I have done this to test that all is seen properly in my app,

```
private void setTestMode(boolean test) {

        if (test) {
            adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
            // GALAXY S3 --Elías
            adRequest.addTestDevice("6XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX9");
        }

    }
```

and in the onCreate method i use it : `setTestMode(true);`
Now i want to upload the app to the Store. Is necessary to put the method to "false", or I can  leave it in "true"? My users can have problems if I leave it in true?

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your users will not be affected since their device ID is different than yours: `6XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX9` However if they manage to install your application on an emulator, then they will get the test Ads.

Comment: Ok, so I going to let it in true, to avoid "false" clicks or similars to my account on admob ^^.  Thanks a lot!